# Inconsistent formatting of numbers (toLocaleString) when executing testcafe-e2e tests inside docker-image

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe, alpine-linux

I am using the testcafe docker image for e2e-testing react components.
When using `Number.prototype.toLocaleString` I am not receiving the expected results for different locales I am testing with.

*Local test:*
[image: Test running on local machine]

*Container test:*

[image: Test running in container]

As you can see the outcome is inconsistent and the containered test run does not seem to properly apply the localization.

Since this oddity can be reproduced with chromium and firefox I am suspecting that the problem derives from the system level.

I could hardly find any information about browser related issues when using them inside a alpine-linux based container.

I stumbled upon this article https://grrr.tech/posts/2020/add-locales-to-alpine-linux-docker-image/ but the issue cannot be redeemed:
I created a new image from testcafe/testcafe:latest with the mentioned steps an made sure `locale` was available.
Still numbers and dates are not formatted consistently.

Comment: It looks like the issue is related to alpine linux, so unfortunately TestCafe team cannot offer a solution as to how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was not able to find a proper workaround, yet.